What type of Visa do I need for a paid internship in Germany?
Hello I am currently a student at UCSD in San Diego, California and have received an internship offer in Germany from April 1, 2025-June 30, 2025. This internship will be paid on a monthly basis. I was just wondering where I even needed to start with the documents since there are many things I currently need such as the residence permit, work permit, health insurance, tax ID, and social security number. I have done research and have found out about the Schengen Visa but I don't know if this covers paid internships as well. I also am not sure what the correct order I need to receive these documents is. I have also found that if the internship is 90 days or less (which it is), citizens of some countries (South Korea is listed as one of those) do not need an internship Visa, is that true even though the internship will be paid? Any help would be great, I am pretty lost so far. Thank you!

Did you ask the company/university about this? If you are not the first, they should know, and if you are the first: the need to know for the next person, and so they may help you.
